# PHP error messages triggered including wordpress php file

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I would like to run a php script with an ajax request. I got it all working except for warning messages that appear upon triggering the ajax request. The functionality of the script works fine, however, I would like to solve the warning messages or suppress them if they aren't important.

Here is the script file.

```
<?php
//If the warnings aren't important, uncomment
//error_reporting(0);
//Required include for the wp_mail() function 
include '../../../wp-load.php';

$to = 'emailhere@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Donation to cbc at' . ' ' . time();
$body = 'The email body content';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
?>
```

Here are the warnings produced

```
Warning: include(../../../wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/cbc/public_html/wp-content/themes/bento/page-example.php on line 5

Warning: include(../../../wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/cbc/public_html/wp-content/themes/bento/page-example.php on line 5

Warning: include(): Failed opening '../../../wp-load.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php56/lib/php') in /home2/cbc/public_html/wp-content/themes/bento/page-example.php on line 5
```

I have tried multiple different types of `includes` and `requires` for the `wp-load.php` that I have found on stackoverflow. All of them that I've tried so far have produced warnings, although some produce different warnings. Again, the functionality works, but these errors are concerning.

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct directory path for wp-load.php?

Comment: It has to be because without the include I do not receive the email. Also this file is three levels up as the three `../` would indicate.

Comment: warnings seem clear, what dont you understand?

Comment: But your starting directory might not be the one this script is in. Perhaps using \_\_DIR\_\_ would help ensure it's from the directory this script is in.

Comment: I don't understand why it exists in the first place because the function works. It IS finding the file to open.

Comment: Well another thing to consider is that include will continue running even if the file is missing. If you use require() then it will stop running when the file can't be found.

Comment: Require produces a fatal error and does not work at all. This is an ajax request so I shouldn't be navigating away from the page. Using  `include __DIR__ . "../../../page-example.php";` instead produces 2 errors instead of 3.

Comment: The purpose of Require is to produce a fatal error instead of just letting the error go without stopping. You might need an extra / after the DIR since I don't think it ends with on and your .. will be part of the directory name instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$my_url= explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $my_url[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
```

Instead of

```
include '../../../wp-load.php';
```

Comment: This way causes no errors to show up, however the function no longer functions either.

Comment: is this the local development or live? have you setup the mail server?? Try to dump the result of wp_mail and see what is causing the failure in delivering the mail.